# How to use router navigation in a service for resolvers in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, error-handling, router, resolver

I'm using the following `ErrorHandleService` which is called everytime an error in any service occures.

```
handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

  const errorBody = error.json();

  const userMessage = this.getUserMessage(errorBody.error);
  if (error.status === 403 || error.status === 404) {
    this.router.navigate(['error']);
  } else {
    if (userMessage === 'Es ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut') {
      this.logError(operation, errorBody.error).subscribe();
      console.log('An error has occured: ' + operation + ' (' + error.status + ')');
    }
    return throwError(userMessage);
  }
};
```

For some components I have implemented resolvers. The **problem** is:

If a HTTP error (403 or 404) occurs while accessing a route with a resolver, `this.router.navigate['error']` doesn't work (there is shown only the empty page). Otherwise - without resolvers - everthing works and the user is forwareded to the error component if an `403` or `404` error occurs.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

My resolvers simply look like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class GetStaffsResolver implements Resolve<Array<Staff>> {

  constructor(private ss: StaffService) { }

  resolve(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.ss.getStaffs(activatedRoute.queryParams['branch']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Router.navigate` is a method, not an array. Try calling it with

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('error');
```

instead of `this.router.navigate['error']`.